# How to retrieve email id of facebook?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm doing a project in mailing system.
In my application I want to retrieve all my email ids of my facebook login and integrate in myapplication.
How to do this????
Anybody please give any idea......

Thanx in advance......

Answer (score 0):

Does this help [How do I import Facebook friends from another website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79496/how-do-i-import-facebook-friends-from-another-website)

Answer (score 0):

By "email ids" I assume you mean email addresses.

You need to obtain the `email` extended permission.  After you get this permission from the user you can use FQL to retrieve the email address of the user.

You cannot obtain the email addresses of their friends.  They need to be users of your app and grant you the `email` extended permission.